# Analyzing network architecture with TDA

Tags: machine-learning, network-topology

I'm doing Neural Architecture Search (NAS) by varying the number of layers and neurons per layer for a neural network (connections are feed-forward throughout), and then training it on a fixed task to test its performance. The end goal is to perform topological data analysis (TDA) on the best and worst architectures (graphs) to spot the persistent structures in a good/bad architecture.

My question is: am I right in my assumption that TDA could spot such persistent structures? If so, which metric should I use? Just the connection weights?

P.S.: My background in (computational) topology is quite minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the previously interested and for those to come, I'd recommend reading through this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09764. The authors open-source their code as well. AFAIK, this is limited to feed-forward networks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know is to try it; or to find someone else who has tried it (e.g., by searching the research literature for a published paper that has tried this approach).